# Passing data from javascript jquery to C# http post fails to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Am trying to pass data from jquery to asp.net mvc controller to get a response but fails to work

This is what i have tried

In jquery

```
 $('#Emp_Payroll_No').change(function () {
        var empdata = $(this).val();
        $.post('/tblHandOvers/GetEmployee', { payrollno: empdata}).then(function (res) {
            console.log("response is", res);  //res is always empty

        })
    })
```

In my c# code

```
        public JsonResult GetEmployee(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        string passedtext = context.Request.Form["payrollno"].ToString();

        var PersonsQuery = db.vwEmployee_HandoverContact.Where(x => x.Emp_Payroll_No == passedtext);
        return Json(PersonsQuery);
    }
```

so am trying to pass payrollno

When using a manual value eg: EMP2001 in the controller it works like

```
        public JsonResult GetEmployee(HttpContext context)
     {
        var PersonsQuery = db.vwEmployee_HandoverContact
                             .Where(x => x.Emp_Payroll_No == "EMP2001 "); //passed manually
        return Json(PersonsQuery);
    }
```

How do i go about this?

Comment: You appear to have the parameter type as HttpContext for your post. This should just be string payrollno

Comment: @Wheels73 should i pass this in a url or what do you specifically mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your C#, I would update to this:

```
        public JsonResult GetEmployee(string payrollno)
{
    var PersonsQuery = db.vwEmployee_HandoverContact.Where(x => x.Emp_Payroll_No == payrollno);
    return Json(PersonsQuery);
}
```